# knockout js - replace bound text

Tags: knockout.js

What is the best way to modify bound text for display purposes?

computed field, custom binding, etc?

For example, you have an object "Foo" in  with property "Bar" that is a string, that has dashes, and you want to replace the dashes with line breaks 
:

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/yUceG/

JavaScript:

```
function MyViewModel() {
     this.theFoo = { Bar: "abc-def-xyz" };
     }
     ko.applyBindings(new MyViewModel());
```

The view could look like this

```
<div data-bind="with: theFoo">
   <span data-bind="text : Bar" />
</div>
```

or this -

```
<!--ko with: theFoo -->
   <!--ko text: Bar--><!--/ko-->
<!--/ko-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is with a custom binding handler.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.lineBreaks = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, data, context) {        
        $(element).html(value.replace(/-/g, '<br />'));      
    }
};
```

See [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rwisch45/t5EqM/3/)

And if the value of the observable might change, then you can add an update section to the binding handler with the same code that is in the init.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.lineBreaks = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, data, context) {          
        $(element).html(value.replace(/-/g, '<br />'));      
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings, data, context) {
        $(element).html(value.replace(/-/g, '<br />'));      
    }
};
```

Now the displayed value will be formatted via the binding handler when the value of the observable updates.

You can probably achieve the same effect with an [extender](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/extenders.html) as well.